# mysql saving ī and other "foreign" characters as "?"

Tags: mysql, unicode

When I run the following query;

```
INSERT INTO authors (name) VALUES ("Alī al-Ḥājj");
```

The row is inputted into mysql as the following;

```
Al? al-H??jj
```

The ī char is being replaced as a question mark.

I originally thought it was a Unicode issue, but my server and table have the following configuration;

```
SET character_set_server = 'utf8mb4';
SET collation_server = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';

CREATE TABLE authors (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(150) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  personal_name VARCHAR(150) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

What am I missing here?

Thank you,

Comment: It could be the program that it is being *displayed* in which is showing the question marks (perhaps a font without the correct glyphs is being used) - it could still be the correct data stored in the database.

Comment: it is probably worth noting that this is being displayed in SequelPro

Comment: Please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58504380/edit) to add the output of `select hex(name) from authors where id = …` (From the command-line: `mysql -u $DATABASE_USER -p $DATABASE -e 'select hex(name) from authors'`)

Comment: See "question mark" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored